# What does the agent mean in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to use jenkins. But when I reading the Declarative Pipeline Syntax, I confused by the `agent` term

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline

1. What does the agent stand for?
2. Is that mean I can set the pipeline runtime folder path?
3. How to create an agent?
4. How set a label for agent?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can feel you :-D.
Here are the answers:

1. The agent section specifies where the entire Pipeline, or a specific stage, will execute in the Jenkins environment depending on where the agent section is placed. The section must be defined at the top-level inside the pipeline block, but stage-level usage is optional. - Content copied from the [agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) section
2. NO, this has nothing to do with the pipeline runtime folder path.
3. You can for example Create an agent/node by the following tutorial:
   [How to Setup Jenkins Agent/Slave Using Password and ssh Keys](https://devopscube.com/setup-slaves-on-jenkins-2/). -
   But there are many other ways to create an agent e.g. using a Docker-Container (...).
4. You can Set a label under the Configuration of the Node.
   You can use a label in your pipeline like:

   ```
    pipeline {
    agent { label 'labelName' }
    (...)
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks too much, I've understand it.

Comment: Can you please explain what it means by 'agent any' ?

Comment: Execute the Pipeline, or stage, on any available agent.

Answer (score 2):

While @adbo covered questions asked, Jenkins [glossary](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/) describes agent really well:

> typically a **machine**, or **container**, which connects to a Jenkins controller and **executes tasks when directed by the controller**.

You can choose to run entire pipeline on any available agent (`agent any` at the top of the pipeline) or run a specific stage on the agent of choice e.g. run build stage in a specific environ by overriding agent in that stage:

`agent { docker { image 'my image' } }`