# Jenkins pipeline agent with label or node call slave node?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

Someone ask about how to create an agent and it create a slave node ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651682/what-does-the-agent-mean-in-jenkins/47652449#47652449)), and I don't know if it's true or no :

```groovy
agent {
  label 'my-defined-label'
}
```

and

```groovy
agent {
  node {
    label 'my-defined-label'
    customWorkspace '/some/other/path'
  }
}
```

So 'my-defined-label' is just slave name?

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can match an exact node name, a label, any other supported label expression. For example, `java8 && linux`, `(docker || java) && !windows` , and `corp-agent-node-01-name` are all valid label syntax.

The [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-node-code-allocate-node) is clear about how the built in syntax works:

> Allocates an executor on a node (typically a slave) and runs further code in the context of a workspace on that slave.
>
> `label` - Computer name, label name, or any other label expression like `linux && 64bit` to restrict where this step builds. May be left blank, in which case any available executor is taken.
>
> *Valid Operators*
>
> The following operators are supported, in the order of precedence.
>
> - **(expr)** - parenthesis
> - **!expr** - negation
> - **expr&&expr** - and
> - **expr||expr** - or
> - **a -> b** - "implies" operator. Equivalent to !a|b. For example, windows->x64 could be thought of as "if run on a Windows slave, that slave must be 64bit." *It still allows Jenkins to run this build on linux.
> - **a <-> b** - "if and only if" operator. Equivalent to a&&b || !a&&!b. For example, windows<->sfbay could be thought of as "if run on a Windows slave, that slave must be in the SF bay area, but if not on Windows, it must not be in the bay area."
>
> All operators are left-associative (i.e., a->b->c <-> (a->b)->c ) An expression can contain whitespace for better readability, and it'll be ignored.
>
> Label names or slave names can be quoted if they contain unsafe characters. For example, "jenkins-solaris (Solaris)" || "Windows 2008"